# Python IDLE won't import script (gives error) but script works fine from textwrangler

Tags: python, import, python-idle, textwrangler

I have a .py script that runs perfectly in TextWrangler but will not work when I try to imported into Terminal or IDLE. I keep getting this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "stdin", line 1, in "module"
File "c.py", line 1
     bookic08ic14x.is32

I have no idea what this means. I always make sure that I am in the correct directory before I make the import.

My code looks like the following:

```
def choice():
import random
print "This program decides who has to do the job"
n = input("How many people are there?:")
people = []
for i in range (1, n+1):
    subject = raw_input("Person %s:" % i)
    people.append(subject)
print random.choice(people)
```

choice()

Also if anyone has suggestions for making this code better I am open to that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import the `random` module first, before defining the function.

```
import random
def choice():
    print ("This program decides who has to do the job")
    n = input("How many people are there?:")
    people = []
    while len(people)<int(n):
        subject=input("Enter the names: ")
        people.append(subject)
    x=random.choice(people)
    return x
print (choice())
```

This is better, if you don't use `return` in your function then you can't use your function wherever you want. For example, with this way you can use your function with `.format` method.
This one running perfectly, I checked.

Comment: and please check it as correct answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Works great thank you! I just changed input to raw_input in the while loop so that I wouldn't have make each name into a string in IDLE.

Comment: You must be using 2.x.  3.x input == 2.x raw_input.  There are rare occasions where putting an import inside a function is appropriate, but doing so is normally a pure waste.  PEP 8, and I, recommend spaces around '=' in assignment statements (but no spaces for arg=value in a function call).  Makes code easier to read.